# Why this reverse array method isnt working?

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I am trying to make a method to reverse an array, I don't know why it is not working?

When I said `int[] arr = array`, I want to do this so it will not be affected so I can use the elements for the second `for` loop and it should have elements `{1,2,3,4,5,6}` but when I use

```
for (int i=array.Length-1;i>array.Length/2;i--)
{
    array[i] = arr[array.Length - 1 - i];
}
```

In this case I have 6 elements so `array.Length` is 6 and since I started from `array.Length-1` it must start from the last element and it must be `array[5]=arr[6-1-5]` which must be `array[5]=arr[0]` and `arr[0]` is 1 but I think it is getting it as 6, why?

Here is the complete code:

```
// ReverseArray method
static int [] ReverseArray(int [] array)
{
    int[] arr = array;
    for (int i=0; i<array.Length/2;i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[array.Length-1  - i];
    }
    for (int i=array.Length-1;i>array.Length/2;i--)
    {
        array[i] = arr[array.Length - 1 - i];
    }
    return array;
}

// Method for displaying elements of Array
static void DisplayArray(int [] array)
{
    int i;
    Console.Write("{");
    for (i = 0; i < array.Length-1; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i] + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(array[i] + "}");
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6};
    ReverseArray(array);
    DisplayArray(array);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to tag the language? Looks like C# to me, but I'm not betting my job on it.

Comment: Try to run your code in a debugger and see what is happening on each line.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes its c# sorry

Comment: Hint: by the time you've made the first half of the array look like the second half in reverse order, how do you expect to get at the data that *was* in the first half?

Comment: I have to ask, are you aware there is a BCL function [Array.Reverse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3877932(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I don't even know what BCL is

Comment: @NightOwl888 I assumed that this is a homework assignment or something (I could be wrong, though) - if so, that would kill the point of the assignment.

Comment: `BCL = .NET Base Class Library` (basically, the .NET platform). In other words, built-in functionality that you don't necessarily have to write yourself (unless of course the built-in one doesn't meet your needs or this is a learning exercise).

Comment: @EJoshuaS no its not homework just our teacher said that we must learn to make our own methods for everything that is in C# and not just use methods someone else made , so I was trying to make reverse because I thought it was simply as that

Comment: @NightOwl888 ah I know it exist but I just wanted to make my own

Comment: @EndritShabani Still a learning assignment, though, correct?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I could say halfway correct

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your reversal approach is invalid: rather than *swapping* elements at indexes `i` and `array.Length-1  - i`, your code *copies* the tail portion of the array onto the initial one, effectively "folding" the array onto itself.

You need to remove the second loop, and replace the assignment with a swap: make a temporary variable, store `array[i]`, copy `array[array.Length-1  - i]`, then write the temporary in its place.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't help myself but start to write a piece of code trying to solve it.

```
    int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    arr = Reverse(arr).ToArray();
```

Here is the shorter way to achieve that.

```
    public IEnumerable<int> Reverse(int[] arr)
    {
        for (int i = arr.Length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            yield return arr[i];
        }
    }
```